# React Native WebView onMessage() is not triggered

Tags: typescript, react-native, webview, postmessage, react-native-webview

I have a static site hosted on S3 with CloudFront distro on top of it.

```
<WebView
  ref={webViewRef}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  source={{ uri: Config.REMOTE_URL }} // CloudFront URL
  sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
  onMessage={(event) => receivedMessageFromWebView(event.nativeEvent.data)}
/>
```

And the way we `postMessage()` to the web is something like this

```
const sendDataToWebView = (dataMap: any) => {
  const dataToPost = { type: 'data', data: dataMap };
  const postMessageJSCode = `
    window.postMessage(${JSON.stringify(dataToPost)}, "*");
    true;
  `;
  if (webViewRef && webViewRef.current) {
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(postMessageJSCode);
  }
}
```

And the `onMessage` implementation as follows

```
const receivedMessageFromWebView = (msgData: any) => {
  console.log('Data Received from WebView -->', msgData); // <-- Not working
};
```

What am I missing here?

- React: 17.0.2
- ReactNative: 0.64.2
- WebView: 11.6.5

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `window.postMessage` try `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage`

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onmessage

Or the documentation is already really details for communicating between native and the webview here: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native